# Open and closed set

Tags: general-topology

Show that:

**(1)** Every open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is an open set.

**(2)** The interior of a closed ball is the open ball.
I need a geometric interpretation.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide your definition of an open set. In most treatments of the topology of Euclidean spaces, open balls are open sets by definition.

Comment: The question is of course a fine fit for a Q&A format; the reason given for closure is rubbish.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Which question? There is no question here, just an order. (And you might want to cut on the systematic stridency of your interventions about the closure of questions, there are other ways to express your personal views.)

Comment: @Did: The implied question is obvious; it’s disingenuous in the extreme to pretend that there is no question here. And I don’t consider an accurate characterization of the reason given for closure to be at all strident.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Please cut on the rhetoric: there is no question asked here, and you know it (and if there was a question, this would be a bad question, and you know it). Scare tactics towards users who vote to close a question, even if such votes displease you for reasons of principle, are not necessary (in the present case, "of course" and "rubbish" are pure bullying).

Comment: @Did: I know nothing of the kind. There very obviously is a question, and I don’t consider it a bad question. And both ‘of course’ and ‘rubbish’ are precisely correct.

Answer (score 3):

An open ball is a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ of the form
$$B_{\delta}(a)=\{x\in\mathbb{R^n}: |x-a|<\delta\}$$

with $\delta>0$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning the set of points in $R^{n}$ whose euclidean distance from $a$ is less than $\delta$.

A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open if $x\in E$ implies that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq E$, for a suitable $\epsilon>0$, i.e. whenever a point is in $E$, a whole sferical neighborhood of the point is itself contained in $E$. But you can easily see that this surely happens for "open balls": take a point in the open ball $B_{\delta}(a)$, call it $P$, then take a ball around $P$ of radius less than $\delta -|P-a|$.

Now, the interior part of any subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the collection of point of $E$ such that you can find a suitable open ball around the point, that is contained in $E$. You can check that the interior part of $E$ is the greatest (w.r.t set-theoretic inclusion) open subset of $E$. When $E$ is a closed ball, this is necessarily the open ball with the same radius of $E$

Comment: Thank you very much@Federica Maggioni

Answer (score 1):

This is not an independent answer to your first question; this picture is simply to help you visualize what’s going on in Federica’s answer to that question.

[image]

I will add a little to her answer to the second question, though. Let $S$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ centred at some point $a\in\Bbb R^n$. Then $$S=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:\|x-a\|\le r\}\;.$$ Thus, every point $x\in S$ falls into one of two categories: either $\|x-a\|<r$, in which case $x\in B(a,r)$, the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $a$, or $\|x-a\|=r$. In the picture above, the latter case corresponds to the points on the large circle.

In the first question you’ve shown that every point of $B(a,r)$ is in the interior of $S$. To show that $B(a,r)$ **is** the interior of $S$, you must show that if $\|x-a\|=r$, then $x$ is not in the interior of $S$. In other words, you must show that no matter how small an $\epsilon>0$ you take, $B(x,\epsilon)\nsubseteq S$. You can do this by explicitly finding a point of $B(x,\epsilon)\setminus S$. Here’s a hint: use a point $a+t(x-a)$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$; for $t\ge 0$ such points are on the ray from $a$ through $x$.

Comment: This is very helpful for me. Gratitude!@Brian M. Scott

Comment: @DawlWhite: You’re very welcome.